# How to get my wifi hotspot ssid in my current android system

Tags: java, android, wifi, ssid

I have a problem that I couldn't find my wifi hotspot ssid in my Android system.
I found many information from google, but nothing helpful.
Please help me to solve it.

Comment: What have you tried so far, other than fruitless Google searches? Have you looked through the [WifiManager API documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)?

Comment: Oh~the API always gets connection ssid, not my current system ssid

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is not a forum; __this is a questions and answer site, and I'm afraid your post isn't really a question, because [real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).__ [Please read the FAQ for more information.](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: What do you mean by "system ssid"?

Comment: he's right. So do you solve it out? :D

Answer (score 52):

You can use [WifiManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) and [WifiInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html) for getting Wifi SSID

```
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
   Log.d("wifiInfo", wifiInfo.toString());
   Log.d("SSID",wifiInfo.getSSID());
```

Also add Permission in your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE">
                                                            </uses-permission>
```

Comment: Oh~this method I tried before, it just can get my current connection ssid, but can't get my wifi hotspot ssid in my android system

Comment: i think he should noted that this might be working only if he turned on his WIfi first.

Comment: Doesn't work on Android 8.1. `# dumpsys wifi | grep mWifiInfo` gives `mWifiInfo SSID: <unknown ssid>, BSSID: <none>, MAC: ..., Supplicant state: DISCONNECTED, RSSI: -127, Link speed: -1Mbps, Frequency: -1MHz, Net ID: -1, Metered hint: false, score: 0`

Comment: Same for me, does not work on Android 7.1.1, it returns a NetworkInfo but with SSID <unknwon>

Answer (score 9):

Here: http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html is the full documentation on the WifiManager.

Note that some of the methods are only available through inspection, as is the method you need `getWifiApConfiguration`.

```
WifiManager wifimanager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
Method[] methods = wifimanager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m: methods) {           
    if (m.getName().equals("getWifiApConfiguration")) {
        WifiConfiguration config = (WifiConfiguration)m.invoke(wifimanager);

            // here, the "config" variable holds the info, your SSID is in
            // config.SSID
    }
}
```

O, and because this stuff is marked hidden, it can change or be completely removed in any future version of Android. So, don't rely on it too much on "official" apps, unless you make that very clear.

Comment: that's make sense. BUt I wonder. How could we change our own device name ? through the UI Settings of course we know, but through code, do u have clue @BartFriederichs?

Comment: @gumuruh I have been fiddling with that, and it is possible by setting the configuration. Use inspection to get to the right calls. Note though that those parts of the API can be changed or removed at any time and break your app. Use at your own risk.

Comment: This API is also protected by a permission that's signature protected now. Only system apps can call it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `WifiInfo.getSSID()` ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getSSID%28%29

Comment: I tried before, it just can scan other wifi hotspots, not my current android system ssid

Comment: The documentation states that this function returns the SSID of the _current_ network.

Comment: I need to get the wifi hospot ssid which I set in my android system, not the current connection ssid in the network.

Comment: If this is what you mean, try WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()

Comment: He needs to find a way to get the SSID of the network his Android device is broadcasting, not the SSID of the network he is connected to, if I understand this correctly