# Android tether - get current SSID

Tags: android, android-wifi, tethering

Duplicate question - [How to get my wifi hotspot ssid in my current android system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599569/how-to-get-my-wifi-hotspot-ssid-in-my-current-android-system)
Sorry for duplicate this qustion, but it still doesn't have the answer. My mobile in tethering mode, so I want to know SSID of it. How can I find this one? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late but i recently managed to get the SSID of the device's hotspot. It's working on my Galaxy Nexus, but haven't tested it quite much.

```
public static WifiConfiguration getWifiApConfiguration(final Context ctx) {
    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    final Method m = getWifiManagerMethod("getWifiApConfiguration", wifiManager);
    if(m != null) {
        try {
            return (WifiConfiguration) m.invoke(wifiManager);
        } catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static Method getWifiManagerMethod(final String methodName, final WifiManager wifiManager) {
    final Method[] methods = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        if (method.getName().equals(methodName)) {
            return method;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Just call getWifiApConfiguration(getActivity()).SSID to get the hotspot name. Nullpointer check is recommended before ;)

Comment: After Android O, this code require specific permission (source :https://stackoverflow.com/a/15121282/4965913). Anybody know how to make this code works after Android O please ?

Comment: I found this to get some information : https://stackoverflow.com/a/45996578/4965913

Answer (score 2):

```
WifiManager mng = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE).

String currentSSID = mng.getConnectionInfo().getSSID()
```

Comment: This answer was described in duplicate question. As it answered it can't get my wifi hotspot ssid!

Comment: No. It returns me SSID of my WiFi router.

Comment: Exactly@Nolesh. We want the ssid for wifi ap not wifi router. Did you find any solution?