# Android Studio: is possible to have hotspot with internet access? (Local Only Hotspot)

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, hotspot

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm using the functionality of Local Only Hotspot to turn on and off programmatically the hotspot (found this two post for reference: [How to turn on/off wifi hotspot programmatically in Android 8.0 (Oreo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984345/how-to-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-in-android-8-0-oreo),[How to turn on Wifi-Hotspot programmatically on Android >= 7.1 (including sharing the internet access)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278186/how-to-turn-on-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-on-android-7-1-including-sharin) .

```
     private void turnOnHotspot() {
    wifiManager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(new 
      WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback() 
     {
        @Override
        public void onStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation) {
            super.onStarted(reservation);
            hotspotReservation = reservation;
            String key = hotspotReservation.getWifiConfiguration().preSharedKey;
            String ussid = hotspotReservation.getWifiConfiguration().SSID;
            System.out.println("KEY: "+ key);
            System.out.println("USSID: "+ ussid);
            currentConfig = hotspotReservation.getWifiConfiguration();
            System.out.println("STARTED THE HOTSPOT");
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            super.onStopped();
            System.out.println("STOPPED THE HOTSPOT");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(int reason) {
            super.onFailed(reason);
            System.out.println("FAILED THE HOTSPOT");
        }
    }, new Handler());
}
private void turnOffHotspot() {
    active = false;
    if (hotspotReservation != null) {
        hotspotReservation.close();
        System.out.println("CLOSE HOTSPOT");
    }
}
```

But from what I gather from other older posts and documentation, this method gives a local network without internet access and a random SSID and Password that cannot be personalised.
I need to connect only one device to this hotspot to share the mobile data (to have internet access), but I didn't find anything that could have help me. Is there another alternative?