# How to turn off wifi hotspot programmatically in Android 8.0 (Oreo) (setWifiApEnabled is not support this version anymore)

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-8.0-oreo, hotspot

I reference the code to turn on hotspot in Android 8.0, it is work. But I have no idea about how to disable it

```java
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void turnOnHotspot(){
    WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    manager.startLocalOnlyHotspot(new WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback(){

        @Override
        public void onStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation) {
            super.onStarted(reservation);
            Log.d(TAG, "Wifi Hotspot is on now");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
            super.onStopped();
            Log.d(TAG, "onStopped: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailed(int reason) {
            super.onFailed(reason);
            Log.d(TAG, "onFailed: ");
        }
    },new Handler());
}
```

I want to use close() method from `LocalOnlyHotspotReservation` , but how to get the reservation instance from outside, like `reservation.close()`;

Or any way can disable hotspot in Android 8.0

**[Update]** I found a way can disable hotspot

```java
wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);                    
Method method = wifiManager.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("cancelLocalOnlyHotspotRequest");
method.invoke(wifiManager);
```

But still, have no idea about how to use close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android turn On/Off WiFi HotSpot programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394599/android-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically)

Comment: But for Android O , it is not support setWifiApEnabled anymore , it provide LocalOnlyHotspotCallback and LocalOnlyHotspotReservation to enable hotspot.

Comment: @Lee Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984345/how-to-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-in-android-8-0-oreo/45996578#45996578

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable it, you need to create a global reference for the WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation, assign it in the onSatrted() callback and then close it as follows

```
private WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation mReservation;

private void turnOffHotspot() {
 if (mReservation != null) {
  mReservation.close();
 }
}
```

You may refer to the following link as follows, it worked for me: 
[How to turn on/off wifi hotspot programmatically in Android 8.0 (Oreo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984345/how-to-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-in-android-8-0-oreo)