# Create custom hotspot in Android 8.0 Oreo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, android-8.0-oreo, hotspot

I am trying to figure out how to setup a custom hotspot with a certain ssid and pass on Android Oreo. I know that there is a way to toggle the hotspot, but I can't seem to find a way to configure the hotspot to have a certain ssid and pass. Is there any way to do this now?

Comment: may this useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50169004/how-to-create-wifihotspot-in-oreo-programmatically/50170577 or https://medium.com/@jean.creuzedeschatelliers/how-to-activate-the-mobile-hotspot-on-android-programmatically-or-not-5931e44097e3

Comment: @AndroidUser Both links do not give much info. The first one is just saying that they are not sure how to do it, and the second one says how to do it pre-oreo.