# How to change WifiConfigration in Oreo device

Tags: android, reflection, android-8.0-oreo, hotspot

I used https://github.com/aegis1980/WifiHotSpot code to start and stop Hotspot from my application. But it will only start and stop the hotspot that cannot change the Wifi configuration, I also want to change the SSID and password. I know how to do that thing under the Oreo device. Can anyone help me get the same result in Oreo.

Answer (score -1):

ONLY POSSIBLE IF YOUR APP IS RUNNING AS SYSTEM APP

In that case, I'm able to do this by using the below class:

https://github.com/anujjpandey/HotSpotOnOreo/blob/master/WifiAndDataConfigs.java

You can use the same

Comment: it's not working it throw exception "java.lang.SecurityException: App not allowed to read or update stored WiFi AP config (uid = 10495)"

Comment: `Method getConfigMethod = manager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");` works below the oreo version only

Comment: @MJM indeed it's need some permissions  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />

    <permission
        android:name="android.permission.OVERRIDE_WIFI_CONFIG"
        android:protectionLevel="signature|privileged" />

It's working for me on system app

Comment: how can i define my app as system app?

Comment: It can only possible if you are having configuration pemx509 and pk8 files to sign your apk

Comment: configuration pemx509 and pk8 files ? What does it actually means and How can I get this ?

Comment: @Binil you can only do all this if your app is a system app, an app can only be a system app if it is placed on the ROM, and from the ROM vendor you can get this keys.