# error: package com.android.dx.stock does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm a new in android development.
So I'm trying to create an application managing Wifi Hotspot on android 9.

So, I'm trying to implement this code
https://github.com/aegis1980/WifiHotSpot/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/fitc/wifihotspot/MyOreoWifiManager.java
according this solution
[How to turn on/off wifi hotspot programmatically in Android 8.0 (Oreo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984345/how-to-turn-on-off-wifi-hotspot-programmatically-in-android-8-0-oreo/52219887#52219887?newreg=ad7dd8983fea41bdb23b142b33ae25e7)

But import com.android.dx.stock.ProxyBuilder trows Android studio error: package com.android.dx.stock does not exist

How to import this package in the project?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your code instead of an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your dependencies in `build.gradle`:

```
    implementation 'com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker:2.25.0'
```

`ProxyBuilder` class is part of this library so you need to add it to your project first before you can use it.

The error:
`com.android.dx.stock does not exist` means that the package you are trying to access is not part of your code. This usually only happens when you don't add required dependencies to your project.