# How to enable Wifi Tethering in Android 9 or 10

Tags: android, tethering

It was possible to enable the Wifi Tethering. Basically it was granting internet to other devices sharing your data connection and showing a new Wifi SSID. Is that possible now with Android 9 or Android 10? I have read about WifiManager.startLocalOnlyHotspot() but I also read that:

> The network created by this method will not have Internet access

Any ideas on how can we programmatically create a internet access so other devices can use the internet of my device?

Comment: try this, work fine in android 10 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49356255/2099272 you can see a example in git repo

Answer (score -1):

I can tell you that there is no generic 'one-size-fits-all' solution. Anything you come up with will be device dependent (or, more accurately, carrier dependent).
Tethering is disallowed through alot of (about a third of) devices in the US nowadays. This is due to the companies' business plans. The majority of their revenue comes not by selling devices, but by selling data plans.

(EDIT:the paragraph above is referring specifically to AT&T. The "one-third" is a guess albeit a conservative one.)

Therefore, so as not to step on their own toes, they will restrict internet access to the hotspot (or else disable it altogether) on their devices. This is one reason that 'rooting' of devices is so popular nowadays.

Comment: But, as far as I know, the app Tasker is able to do it.

Comment: The app tasker will NOT work on AT&T devices in America, due to the reasons above. There are a lot of apps on the Play Store that claim to enable hotspot. NONE all of them work on AT&T. I can promise you that. Even if you buy a Straight Talk byop kit, which promises free hotspot, it will not work for (former) AT&T devices. That's just the way it is.

Comment: @ton not on at&t devices. They are dead serious about the no sharing thing. I did recently find a workaround through strange talk with an at&t device... for about a week, until they noticed. When they found out, they COMPLETELY disabled the device. I can't use it with any plan now. I tried reaching out to Straight Talk support, and on their end the EMIE shows up as "restricted device." Moral of the story: if you do get it to work, they'll turn your device into a paperweight...  added to let you all know to be careful w/ the workarounds