# How can I learn SSID of that I am connected to wifi point?

Tags: android

I want to learn the connected wif-fi point SSID. By doing so, I will not try to connect to the same point. How can I learn SSID of that I am connected to wifi point ?  Is there a method like isConnected() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599569/how-to-get-my-wifi-hotspot-ssid-in-my-current-android-system

here it is

Comment: @dsvoronin how can I implement forget the communication on the Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
   WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
   Log.d("wifiInfo", wifiInfo.toString());
   Log.d("SSID",wifiInfo.getSSID());
```

you will need the android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

There is one problem:
    I selected wifi "XYZ" whoz pwd was unknwn. Entered some random pwd.
    It shows authentication problem. on wifi screen.

But, Log.d("SSID",wifiInfo.getSSID());
Results into "XYZ"