# Check if user is connected to WIFi on Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, server

I am designing a gaming app, that requires the users to be on a good wifi connection. And i also need both users to know if the other user is on wifi or not. Android platform will be used for this gaming app development.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect network connection type on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802472/detect-network-connection-type-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Just create the following class which checks for an internet connection:

```
public class ConnectionStatus {

    private Context _context;

    public ConnectionStatus(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnectionAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) _context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This class simply contains a method which returns the boolean value of the connection status. Therefore in simple terms, if the method finds a valid connection to the Internet, the return value is `true`, otherwise `false` if no valid connection is found.

The following method in the MainActivity then calls the result from the method previously described, and prompts the user to act accordingly:

```
public void addListenerOnWifiButton() {
        Button btnWifi = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnWifi);

        iia = new ConnectionStatus(getApplicationContext());

        isConnected = iia.isConnectionAvailable();
        if (!isConnected) {
            btnWifi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please connect to a hotspot",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            btnWifi.setVisibility(4);
            warning.setText("This app may use your mobile data to update events and get their details.");
        }
    }
```

In the above code, if the result is false, (therefore there is no internet connection, the user is taken to the Android wi-fi panel, where he is prompted to connect to a wi-fi hotspot.

Comment: "And i also need both users to know if the other user is on wifi or not" .. How does one user know if the other is on wifi or not ?

Comment: Not sure if you can get that easily. 

Came through some posts on SO which could help you like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7599847/1116216. But this only gives you the SSID (Wifi network name) for the network your device is connected to, and not the one of the peer you are palying against.