# How to find the SSID of my Mobile Hotspot (Android studio- java)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-wifi, hotspot

I am hoisting hotspot from my android phone. I was able to host the mobile hotspot programmatically  but I was not able to find the SSID of my phone (which is being used as mobile hotspot). I would appreciate if someone could help me with the code to find the SSID.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but it seems to be similar to what you looking for.

[How to get my wifi hotspot ssid in my current android system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599569/how-to-get-my-wifi-hotspot-ssid-in-my-current-android-system)

Comment: I have tried that. It doesn't help much. I am hosting wifi (hotspotting) from my mobile phone and I need the SSID of my mobile phone. Is there any solution please let me know. I would be grateful